# Is it possible to get a cron job to run between certain hours only?

Tags: linux

I'm editing a crontab for a job that I want to run between friday 10pm to saturday 10pm,I'm not sure if this is possible though .
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Cron can schedule an executable, it doesn't generally limit the run-time. You could schedule it for Friday @ 10pm, or generally any day of the week/time you want.

Comment: i want my job to run between these hours only (friday 10Pm - Saturday 10Pm).Does this answer your question ?

Comment: Does that mean that after saturday 10pm, the job should get killed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understood correctly, you want the job to get killed after Saturday 10PM.

You can do this using the `timeout` command:

For instance if the job is `command arguments`, instead you specify it as:

```
timeout 86400 command arguments
```

where `86400` is the number of second `timeout` will wait before killing the process.

In the crontable this means

```
00 22 * * 5 timeout 86400 command arguments
```

Comment: * 22 * * 5,6 /script/to/execute/     is this right ?

Comment: No `cronjob` only specifies when a process *starts*, so you should not specify `6` as the dow, furthermore it should be `22` (since that's 10PM). Finally you should prefix it with timeout.

Comment: @user3561633 That magic number (`86400`) is `24*60*60`. There are 60 seconds in a minute, there are 60 minutes in a hour, and there are 24 hours in a day. So, this would timeout (kill) the job after 24 hours.

Comment: i want it to run between friday and sat right, without specifying 6 how would it run ?correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You would specify 5 because you want it to start on Friday. If you added 6 it would start (again) on Saturday.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you , i got it now :)

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to do it from timeout:

Best ways it can be achieve through crontab is to

1) have an entry in crontab for a script script1 for Friday 10PM
this script1 runs your target program prog1 and should control the logic which will kill prog1 if it find it keep running at Saturday 10:01PM

2) Have an entry in crontab to run the prog1 at Friday 10PM and have another script script_to_kill scheduled for Saturday 10:01PM  which will check if prog1 is still running if yes then kill.

Killing a script/program have its own issues

Comment: Well of course one should hope the script doesn't do that much I/O or modifies some registers (or only in the beginning of the processing).

Comment: yeah this is useful too.